# Install node_module from npm but it doesn't install its own node_modules - package.json

Tags: node.js, dependencies, node-modules

I just created a node_module with a dependency with 'validator'.
But when I install it from npm, it doesn't install the 'validator' module in its own node_module directory. I don't understand why, but it's the first time I create my own node module.

*package.json:*

```
{
  "name": "validator-extended",
  "description": "String validation and sanitization based on validator.js",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Ayolan/validator-extended",
  "keywords": [
    "validator",
    "validation",
    "validate",
    "sanitization",
    "sanitize",
    "sanitisation",
    "sanitise",
    "assert",
    "extend",
    "extended"
  ],
  "author": "Vadorequest <https://github.com/Vadorequest>",
  "main": "app.js",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Ayolan/validator-extended/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Ayolan/validator-extended.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.8"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/Ayolan/validator-extended/raw/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "validator": "~3.1"
  }
}
```

I also have a .npmignore file with this:

```
########################
# node.js / npm
########################
lib-cov
*.seed
*.log
*.csv
*.dat
*.out
*.pid
*.gz

pids
logs
results

node_modules

npm-debug.log


########################
# misc / editors
########################
*~
*#
.DS_STORE
.netbeans
nbproject
.idea
```

Should I push the node_modules/ directory into my git repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove your existing `package.json` and run

```
npm init
```

to properly initialise your project. Once that's done, add validator to the dependencies. This should allow `npm install` to work properly and install your dependencies. Don't commit your `node_modules` folder.

Comment: I ust did it. I also updated the main post to show how was my old package.json before npm init.

Comment: If the previous package.json was what was causing the problem, you should revert it in the question. This way others with the same problem will recognise it.